# Apply automation in R to change rows of numbers into date

Tags: r, automation, apply

I have created a simple data.frame of 1 column:

```
x<-as.data.frame(replicate(1, sample(1:27, 1250, rep=TRUE)))
```

So x will be a column with repeated values from 1 to 27.

I wish to change these values into dates, eg.

```
x[x==1]<-"31 June 2018"
x[x==2]<-"1 July 2018"
x[x==3]<-"2 July 2018"
```

Is there a faster way to do this?

I believe I can do this using apply... but I have not much experience using apply..
Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: `x$V1 = as.Date("2018-06-30") + x$V1`

Comment: @JonSpring, please contribute comment as answer so I can upvote your answer

Comment: Head's up in case you decide to do a partial update: A column can be one type/class only. In your frame definition, column `V1` is an `integer`; as soon as you try to update even one of its members with something that is `numeric` or `character`, the whole column is converted to that class. So while JonSpring's comment/answer are correct for the whole column, you cannot do `x$V1[1:3] <- as.Date("2018-06-30") + x$V1[1:3]` and expect anything "sane". (The `Date`s will be down-converted to `integers`, so while you haven't lost the rest of `V1`, you also have not set `Date` classes on the top 3.

Comment: Consider `seq(from=as.Date('2018-06-30'), by = '1 day', length.out = 27)`.  Note there is no 31 June.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way with `as.Date()` -

```
x$date <- as.Date(x$V1, origin = "2018-06-30")

head(x)

  V1       date
1  5 2018-07-05
2 19 2018-07-19
3 13 2018-07-13
4  9 2018-07-09
5 10 2018-07-10
6 21 2018-07-21
```

If you want the format to be as per your post -

```
x$date <- as.Date(x$V1, origin = "2018-06-30") %>% format("%d %B %Y")

head(x)

  V1         date
1  5 05 July 2018
2 19 19 July 2018
3 13 13 July 2018
4  9 09 July 2018
5 10 10 July 2018
6 21 21 July 2018
```